# Remove text field soft focus WillPopScope

Tags: flutter, dart

everything is fine to remove the focus from text field except for WillPopScope function, after i press back button the keyboard dismiss but the focus line still in the textfield.

let me know if you need more information about the code

removeFocus Code

```
void removeFocus() {
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  }
```

WillPopScope Code

```
onWillPop: () async {
        removeFocus();
        return true;
      },
```

i mean this blue line won't dismiss

[image]

Comment: are you trying to back (screen B to Screen A) the screen ? and and on the Screen A ,there is a text field and you need to unfocus  it am I right? please give more information about the code?

Comment: i just want to remove the blue lines when i unfocus from textfield, but if put the removeFocus in WillPopScreen it doesn;t work

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using in my project:

```dart
onWillPop: () async {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  return true;
},
```

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change your removeFocus() method as the following:

```dart
void removeFocus() {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
       currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
}
```